# Replace last characters in each line

Tags: sed

I have a csv file with floats ending in a character:

```
1, 2, 6, 7, "p"
1, 6, 7, 2, "e"
```

etc.

I'd like to replace "p" with 0 and "e" with 1 for a classification task. That is, I would like:

```
1, 2, 6, 7, 0
1, 6, 7, 2, 1
```

For all 8000 lines in my file.

I have tried:

```
sed -i 's/"p"$/0' filename.csv
```

and

```
sed -i 's"p"$0//' filename.csv
```

but neither work. How can I replace several characters in each line using sed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed 's/"p"$/0/;s/"e"/1/' file.txt
```

Comment: Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day; teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime.  This is just a fish.

Comment: It's a delicious fish, though!

Comment: Without any explanation I find this answer to be less of a value. | -1

Answer (score 8):

```
sed -e 's/"p"$/0/; t' -e 's/"e"$/1/' filename.csv
```

With `t`, we branch off if the first substitution succeeds, preventing the second substitution from being attempted. That's a common idiom for doing at most one substitution per line.

Comment: @Oskar, see edit.

Answer (score 3):

Your first `sed` is missing the terminating `/`.
Use `sed -i 's/"p"$/0/' filename.csv`

Comment: You could add that the second uses `"` as a delimiter, and is also missing its terminating delimiter :)

Comment: @Aaron The second sed in the question is just plain weird. Even if he added the " at the end, because the $ sign is after the quotes, it won't match the EOL, but rather replace `p` with a literal `$0//`. It was much easier to fix the first one. :)

Comment: Right, I missed that